# Unable to preview in Nativescript Preview on iOSafter scanning in Sidekick

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I’m new to nativescript and I’ve since discovered the only way to develop for iOS on windows is by using Sidekick. However if I try to preview a template app in  Nativescript Preview it gives me the following error:

CONSOLE WARN:

> file:///app/vendor.js:18276:12: Objective-C class name
>   "AnimationDelegateImpl" is already in use - using
>   "AnimationDelegateImpl1" instead.

Comment: I think that's safe to ignore.